# Find the maximum value without computing matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-optimization

I have a optimization problem, which is to find a certain $h^*$ that:$$h^*  = argmax(h'\alpha-\frac{\kappa}{2}h'\Sigma h)$$
where $\alpha$ is a $(n \times 1)$ vector and $\Sigma$ is a $(n\times n)$ matrix.
The $\Sigma$ matrix is of form $$\Sigma = XFX' + D$$
where $X$ is a $(n\times k)$ matrix and $F$ is a covariance matrix of factor loadings, and $D$ is a diagonal matrix. $D = diag(\sigma_1^2,..,\sigma_n^2)$.

How can I write a function to compute $h^*$ without computing the a $(n\times n)$ matrix?

Comment: What kind of matrix is $\Sigma$? Is it perchance diagonal, symmetric, or hermitian?

Comment: @IlikeSerena I have modified the question

Comment: BFGS only requires function evaluations and gradients, which can be computed efficiently for your problem

Comment: @LinAlg Hi, Can you explain it more details? Thank you very much!

Comment: What's this $h^*$? If it's the $\text{argmax}$ of the given expression, shouldn't it just be $h$?

Comment: @IlikeSerena $h^*$ is the optimal $h$ to max the function

Answer (score 1):

A covariance matrix is symmetric. After multiplying with the presumed orthogonal matrix $X$ and its transpose, that will still be the case. The diagonal matrix is also symmetric. So their sum will be as well. In particular it means that $\Sigma'=\Sigma$.

When $h$ is optimal, each partial derivative of the expression must be $0$. Starting with the first:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial h_1}(h'\alpha -\frac\kappa 2h'\Sigma h)
= e_1'\alpha - \frac\kappa 2e_1'\Sigma h - \frac\kappa 2h'\Sigma e_1
= e_1'\alpha - \kappa e_1'\Sigma h
= \alpha_1 - \kappa \sigma_1 h = 0
$$
where $\sigma_1$ is the first row vector of $\Sigma$.

Extending to a vector and to a matrix again:
$$\nabla (h'\alpha -\frac\kappa 2h'\Sigma h) = \alpha - \kappa \Sigma h = 0$$

We can find $h^*$ now by solving:
$$\Sigma h^* = \frac 1\kappa \alpha \implies h^*=\frac 1\kappa\Sigma^{-1}\alpha$$

This can be done with for instance Gaussian elimination, or otherwise with a more advanced method that is more robust.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Qing how does this answer your question if you do not want to compute $\Sigma$? Consider using the generalized Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury formula.

Comment: @LinAlg, we don't actually need to compute $\Sigma$. Since $F$ is a covariance matrix, we're talking about a probability cloud around a mean. Statistically the most likely solution is if we substitute $D$ for $\Sigma$. I only realized this just now though. My answer was just to solve the optimization problem with a solution that is as simple as possible.

Comment: @IlikeSerena there are many ways to cope with uncertainty, just inserting the most likely parameter value is not always the best strategy

Comment: @LinAlg I think you are right, it's not solving the major issue of the $\Sigma$ here though.